# cudaGraphicsMapResources slow speed when mapping DirectX texture

Tags: cuda

I'm writing to a texture in DirectX then reading from it in CUDA kernel. I'm using cudaGraphicsMapResources before launching the kernel. Sometimes it takes  10-30 ms. Of course that causes a framedrop in the application. The texture is only written in DirectX and only read in CUDA, not used anywhere else.

I tried different things, like waiting few frames, but it doesn't always help. I also tried to call cudaGraphicsMapResources  only in the beginning (instead of calling it each time), but then I have no guarantee that the DirectX has already finished to write the texture (sometimes it hasn't). I tried to use threads, but it crashes when I call cudaGraphicsMapResources from different thread.

I also have the impression that it's mostly occurs when vsync is enabled.

Is this a known problem? What causes this? Is there a way to test if the resource is ready in a non blocking way? Or in general is there some workaround?

I have GeForce GTX 670, Windows 7 64 bit, driver ver. 331.82.

Answer (score 2):

From the CUDA documentation on `cudaGraphicsMapResources()`:

> This function provides the synchronization guarantee that any graphics calls issued before cudaGraphicsMapResources() will complete before any subsequent CUDA work issued in stream begins.

It could be that the delays you are seeing are caused by waiting for the drawing to complete. In particular since you indicate that, when not mapping for each frame, the drawing has sometimes not completed.

Combining this with vsync could make the problem worse since graphics calls may have to wait for the next vsync before they start drawing.

A partial workaround for the issue when vsync is in use may be to use more back buffers.

If you haven't already, you could also try to call `cudaGraphicsResourceSetMapFlags()` with `cudaGraphicsMapFlagsReadOnly`.

**Edit:**

I think it waits only for drawing calls made by your own app to complete. The docs say:

> The graphics API from which resources were registered should not access any resources while they are mapped by CUDA. If an application does so, the results are undefined.

And, of course, you have no control over drawing performed by other apps.

You may be able to check drawing status without blocking by calling the `Present()` Direct3D method with the `D3DPRESENT_DONOTWAIT` flag.

Comment: I already use cudaGraphicsMapFlagsReadOnly. I don't understand what exactly is it waiting for? Does it only wait for drawing to my texture to complete (in my case that would be the completion of StretchRect or ResolveSubresource calls) or does it wait that all graphic calls issued before cudaGraphicsResource are executed and the GPU is "free" for CUDA? Or something else? In any case, is there a way to reduce the wait?or to just test if it's ready without blocking?

Comment: "And, of course, you have no control over drawing performed by other apps." No, I mean other graphic calls within the same program. I draw my texture and also do some other stuff.

Comment: @st.: Good question, but I don't know.