# First time executing sort from thrust it takes too long

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda, thrust

im working on a fluid simulator using opengl (implementing the sph algorithm). I've tried many methods to run my simulator, first i used octrees, after that hashmaps and now i am trying to use Z order, and for that i need to order my particles based on their index.

What i am having some trouble understanding is the fact that if i have one thrust::sort it takes 15 miliseconds, if i have two thrust::sort it takes 17 miliseconds.

For more clarification, i am doing my simulator in opengl (all my buffers are created using opengl), and i use cuda interops in order to sort my buffers with thrust, that uses cuda.

This is the part where i get my buffers and "link" them to cuda

```
//I use this if to do the registerBuffer only one time
if (first == 0) {
        //index
        IBuffer* bIndex = RESOURCEMANAGER->getBuffer("particleLib::Index");
        int buffIdIndex = bIndex->getPropi(IBuffer::ID);
        //Position
        IBuffer* bPosition = RESOURCEMANAGER->getBuffer("particleLib::Position");
        int buffIdPosition = bPosition->getPropi(IBuffer::ID);
        //TempIndex
        IBuffer* bTempIndex = RESOURCEMANAGER->getBuffer("particleLib::TempIndex");
        int buffIdTempIndex = bTempIndex->getPropi(IBuffer::ID);
        //Velocity
        IBuffer* bVelocity = RESOURCEMANAGER->getBuffer("particleLib::Velocity");
        int buffIdVelocity = bVelocity->getPropi(IBuffer::ID);

        // register this buffer object with CUDA
        //So devia chamar isto uma vez
        cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(&cuda_ssbo_Index, buffIdIndex, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsNone);
        cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(&cuda_ssbo_TempIndex, buffIdTempIndex, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsNone);
        cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(&cuda_ssbo_Position, buffIdPosition, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsNone);
        cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(&cuda_ssbo_Velocity, buffIdVelocity, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsNone);
        first = 1;
    }
    

    // map OpenGL buffer object for writing from CUDA
    int* dptrssboIndex;
    int* dptrssboTempIndex;
    float4 * dptrssboPosition;
    float4 * dptrssboVelocity;

    cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &cuda_ssbo_Index, 0);
    cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &cuda_ssbo_TempIndex, 0);
    cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &cuda_ssbo_Position, 0);
    cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &cuda_ssbo_Velocity, 0);

    size_t num_bytesssbo_Index;
    size_t num_bytesssbo_TempIndex;
    size_t num_bytesssbo_Position;
    size_t num_bytesssbo_Velocity;

    cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer((void**)&dptrssboIndex, &num_bytesssbo_Index, cuda_ssbo_Index);
    cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer((void**)&dptrssboTempIndex, &num_bytesssbo_TempIndex, cuda_ssbo_TempIndex);
    cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer((void**)&dptrssboPosition, &num_bytesssbo_Position, cuda_ssbo_Position);
    cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer((void**)&dptrssboVelocity, &num_bytesssbo_Velocity, cuda_ssbo_Velocity);

    mysort(&dptrssboIndex,&dptrssboPosition, &dptrssboTempIndex, &dptrssboVelocity,216000);

    cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &cuda_ssbo_Index, 0);
    cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &cuda_ssbo_TempIndex, 0);
    cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &cuda_ssbo_Position, 0);
    cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &cuda_ssbo_Velocity, 0);
```

This is the code from mysort

```
void mysort(int ** index1, float4 ** values1, int** index2, float4 ** values2,int particles){
    
    thrust::device_ptr<int> i1buff = thrust::device_pointer_cast(*(index1));
    thrust::device_ptr<float4> v1buff = thrust::device_pointer_cast(*(values1));
    thrust::device_ptr<int> i2buff = thrust::device_pointer_cast(*(index2));
    thrust::device_ptr<float4> v2buff = thrust::device_pointer_cast(*(values2));

    //sorts
    thrust::stable_sort_by_key(i1buff, i1buff + particles,v1buff); // 15 ms
    //cudaThreadSynchronize();
    thrust::stable_sort_by_key(i2buff, i2buff + particles, v2buff); // 17 ms


    //repetido so para ver o tempo
    thrust::stable_sort_by_key(i1buff, i1buff + particles, v1buff);
    //cudaThreadSynchronize();
    thrust::stable_sort_by_key(i2buff, i2buff + particles, v2buff); //4 sorts -> 19 ms

    //cudaThreadSynchronize();
}
```

Can some one explain what is going on?

Edit1:
I used cudaDeviceSynchronize() to mesure the time (as indicated by @Jérôme-Richard) it takes for each sort, and the first sort always takes longer, even if i change orders.
Another fact is that the first sort takes longer if i have my camera closer to the scene, this indicates that maybe Cuda is wating for opengl to do his work, making the first sort "take longer".
I also tried having no sorts on my mysort() function, the only thing i had inside was the cudaDeviceSynchronize() and it took the 15 miliseconds, again, this indicates that cuda might be wating on opengl to finish the work from the last frame.

Edit2:
I did some more debugging and what i thought appears to be true. The real slow down comes from the cudaGraphicsMapResources calls. According to this ([cudaGraphicsMapResources slow speed when mapping DirectX texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618803/cudagraphicsmapresources-slow-speed-when-mapping-directx-texture)):

> This function provides the synchronization guarantee that any graphics calls issued before cudaGraphicsMapResources() will complete before any subsequent CUDA work issued in stream begins.

So yeah, It is waiting for opengl to draw some stuff, because the camara distance affects the time cudaGraphicsMapResources takes.

Comment: I'm not sure myself, but I reckon the timing of the first sort call includes other operations, like memory allocation and transfer? How exactly are you timing your calls?

Comment: There are a few things that can happen, I assume all the values going into mysort are already on main memory, so subsequent calls to that function with more or less the same values will result in them being left in the cpu cache (faster than memory), therefore giving you some extra performance. If you really really wanted to measure performance as a function of number of calls, use number of iterations like 1000,2000... then normalize. However, the performance of a function in relation to subsequent calls is not as important as performance in relation to the whole program if you are profiling.

Comment: Hi @Beko the sort should not alocate memory because the buffers are on the gpu already. I know the time because i am using a costum engine called Nau3d and the profiler tells me the time each "step" (pass) takes. The times should be correct because i can see the effect of the sorts on the fps's. When i do 1 sort my fps count takes a hit, and when i do 2 sorts the fps almost stays the same.

Comment: Alright. It's just that I had a similar experience before using `nvprof` where the first `cudaMemcpy` after a kernel call took significantly longer than the ones following it. That was because `cudaMemcpy` does an implicit synchronization, so the timer for that `cudaMemcpy` actually included the time it took for the kernel to finish, etc. Perhaps you could still try to measure the time in a more "traditional" way, ie. via `cudaEvents` or something like that (don't know if that works for `Thrust`) and see if the results are different. But other than that I'm pretty clueless unfortunately.

Comment: But judging from your last sentence it probably will not make a difference.

Comment: @Beko i think you are correct. I think cuda is wating for opengl to finish his work, that is why the first sort takes longer. The first sort takes longer the closer i have my camera to the scene (the closer i get the more work opengl has to do). This indicates that cuda might be wating for opengl to finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two important points could explain you observation:

- The first CUDA function call implicitly initialize the runtime (quite slow).
- The actual content of the arrays to be sorted can/often impact performance of a sort (regarding the algorithm used in the Thrust implementation). Once data are sorted, they can be sorted faster because they are already sorted.
- Thrust make few synchronizations (ie. it calls `cudaDeviceSynchronize`) in many provided functions in order to ensure returned data transferred from the GPU can be safely read from the CPU side. It also internally use such kind of synchronization when multiple interdependent CUDA kernels are submitted regarding the result of the computed data (you can see that with the Nvidia profiler). Regarding the previous asynchronous CUDA calls made before this function, the over-synchronization can add an unwanted overhead.

Comment: Hi @Jérôme Richard the first two buffers are not the same, so, both are not ordered, and the increment in time is 2 miliseconds. Maybe is the runtime initializing like you said. Do you know is there is a way to do that only one time ? because my sort runs every frame.

Comment: You can just call `cudaThreadSynchronize` in you main before any computation to get ride of the cuda initialization. I assume you measure the time with the `cudaThreadSynchronize` calls (uncommented) between `thrust::stable_sort_by_key` calls and you include them in your timing. Is it the case?

Comment: I mesure the time using the build in profiler inside the engine i'm using. The engine mesures the time of each "step" (pass) in the simulation. I'll talk with my teacher (that created the engine) and aks him if the times are correct.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. It is `cudaDeviceSynchronize` and *not* `cudaThreadSynchronize`. You can measure the timings yourself using `std::chrono::steady_clock::now();`. Note that timings are retrieved on the CPU side so a `cudaDeviceSynchronize` call is required to ensure you measure the GPU operation correctly (include the overhead of the device synchronization), unless you are sure Thrust do the synchronization.

Comment: Using the cudaDeviceSynchronize i get the same results. Doing sort1 i get 15 miliseconds, doing sort2 i get 2 miliseconds. I even changed the order of the sorts, and i get 15 miliseconds on the first sort and 2 on the second, this means that the content of the buffers is not the fault for the extra time on the first sort.

Comment: Ok. Interesting. So I will probably delete this answer. Can you report those useful information on your post? Out of curiosity: what time you get *without any call* to Thrust and only one call to`cudaDeviceSynchronize` in `mysort`?

Comment: hmmm. With the cudaDeviceSynchronize() only i get 15 miliseconds. I think what is going on is that cuda is wating for opengl to do his stuff. That is why the first one takes longer, the time must include the "waiting" time. The 15 miliseconds can be more or less depending on the distance i have my camera, this indicates that cuda is wating for opengl to finish.

Comment: Ok, good! I added an explanation of this effect in the answer. Please validate the answer if you can confirm the problem comes from this effect.

Comment: I did some more debbuging and the slow down comes from cudaGraphicsMapResources, it waits for the opengl to do all his work first. I've edited that on the main post if you want to read it. Thanks for the help.